# Python pandas : Counting the number of string occurrences in multiple columns for each month

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like the following and 'created_at' contains datetime values;

```
Id   created_at            issue_type        product_version
123  2017-01-01 14:00:00   product failure   version_a
124  2017-02-01 13:40:00   ID10t             version_c
125  2017-02-20 01:40:00   PEBCAK            version_c
```

I need to be able to the occurrences of issue_type and product_version for each month.

So, the results should look like:

```
month issue_type       count    product_version count
Jan   product failure  1        version_a       1
Feb   ID10t            1        version_c       2     
      PEBCAK           1
```

UPDATE:

This gets me part of the way there:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='created_at', freq='M' ['issue_type'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

Move along these lines:

```
df.groupby([df.created_at.dt.month,'product_version']).count()['Id'].reset_index(1)
#           product_version  Id
#created_at                    
#1                version_a   1
#2                version_c   2
```

You'll end up with two dataframes (one for versions, one for issues). You can recombine them later, if necessary.